# Newbie in android development and huge workload, what should I do?

Tags: developer, workload

I'm a newbie android developer and have very basic knowledge of android development. I've joined this new just 1 week ago, and my boss is asking me to convert a huge website into android application. There is huge workload here and this is my first job too. I'm going to work alone in the android development team and I do not have much experience in professioanl android development, there is no one in the company who knows android, company is small, I'm getting under pressure and getting sort of depressed, what should I do?

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, **[this](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696)** and  **[this](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695)** guidance may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: what kind of pressure? it's not surprising for a brand new developer to feel a bit overwhelmed in their first job - it's only been a week though, and you should just feel comfortable that you are new at this.

Comment: Pressure in a sense that, they are expecting a lot from me, which is bit scary too, as I don't have much experience I'm feeling that I won't stand to his standards and would let him down if I do not complete the work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I'm a new developer in a new position and I'm overwhelmed by the position. How do I ease into the position or do I just change jobs?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6223/im-a-new-developer-in-a-new-position-and-im-overwhelmed-by-the-position-how-d)

Comment: @DavidK: Thanks for that link. But my scenario is bit different, as I can't get guidance from any senior developer here, as no one knows the android. More to it I'm the only one who was hired for the position for Mobile Application Developer. There was no such position before in the company.

Comment: @1binary0 You might also look around at [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). I know we recently migrated a question over there about how to handle being an inexperienced sole developer, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: @DavidK this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/40980 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat I wasn't suggesting that this question should be asked at Programmers, more that there might be some questions there that the OP would find useful.

Comment: Do you think you can't handle the job because you're just not capable of doing it (e..g it is too big for one person), or is it one that you could do but you're just overwhelmed from lack of experience on that size project

Comment: @Brandin: Precisely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is nobody in the company that is going to help you with this and you do not have the required skills and insight to fully complete this project alone, raise this issue with your boss. Indicate to him that you are unable to make reasonable/accurate estimates of the time it will take you since there are too many unknown variables for you. Mention that you will need time to deepen your skills and do research in order to complete the project.

Most likely your boss is already aware of these issues - they hired you, so they should be reasonably familiar with your skills - but by raising it and having them sign off on it (preferably in an email or somesuch so you have a trace) you make it *their* problem and not *yours*.

Once you've gotten the confirmation from your boss that they are aware that you will need a lot of time and they accept this, from there on in just do what you can in the time you have, and keep your boss apprised of your progress at all times. If they feel things are going too slowly, that's not *your* responsibility, all you can do is to keep at it. Don't feel pressured to meet unrealistic demands, just do what you can and keep your boss aware of the issues you run into and how you're spending your time.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have knowledge of programming mobile apps (iOS, Windows Phone, anything but Android)?

It sounds to me you haven't talked to your boss yet about the "how". You see, a website can be very substantial and contain many elements and pages. Also, a website is often targeted at much larger screens, so that more things can be displayed or performed on the website.

You can't just plainly transform a website into an app. It doesn't work that way.

Here are 2 options you should consider:

1. Convert the *website* to be compatible with mobile devices
2. Break the website into multiple, smaller parts (for StackExchange pages, i.e.: a View to view a question and its belonging answers, a View to create a Question, and a View to create an Answer, etc.). Out of those parts you can assemble an app

Comment: +1 - seek direction from your boss. you're new, and realistically cannot be expected to set your own direction until you've got some experience at this.

Comment: To answer your question, I have some knowledge of web development. I guess I should provide more info about my work. I understood the workflow of the project, I know how android application will work, I even know how to design that application, part I'm struck at technical part actual coding. For example I know how video streaming from server should work, I don't know how should I implement it.

Comment: A senior developer would help and guide me a lot, I even asked about it in subtle manner, but it seems I'm the only one who is going to work on Android for long time from the company.